# Can an Itō integral be $\infty$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In other words, can $\int_0^t f(s)dW(s)$ = $\infty$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not well defined. When you put something like $\int_0^t f(s) dW(s)$, it has to be finite and usually $f(s)$ belongs to the space 
$$
\Theta:= \{ f: f \mbox{ is progressive measurable or adapted, } \int_0^T f^2_t dt <+\infty\}.
$$
However,
$$
E\left(\int_0^t f(s) dW(s) \right)
$$
can be infinity, when the stochastic integral is only a local martingale, not a true martingale.

Comment: LOL, so if I get an implication from your post, it would be: 1. $\int_0^T f^2_tdt < \infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_0^T f(s)dW(s) < \infty$
2. Even $E[\int_0^T f(s)dW(s)]$ maybe $\infty$, but $\int_0^T f(s)dW(s)$ may still always be finite? LOL... correct me if my understanding from you were wrong. By the way, thanks for your input! appreciated

Comment: When you define the stochastic integral, it is automatically finite. Otherwise, it is not well defined. That is why we require $f$ belongs to some space.

Comment: Ummmm, the integral comes from taking a limit including increments from brownian motion... although we all know brownian motion may have unbounded variation... ummm, gonna provide more details about my questions tonight. :)

Comment: You are right. The limit makes sense only when $f$ belongs to $\Theta$.